# Javascript debugging within cobalt

Tags: cobalt

We at looking at improving the performance of our own web application running on the cobalt browser.

Within cobalt the trace facility is useful to track where the time is spent within the browser itself however there is no info on the time spent in JavaScript since the remote debugging tools are not functional in that regard.

Are there any tools within Cobalt for debugging JavaScript and to be able to get a trace of the JavaScript run during certain events being processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cobalt does expose access to the Cobalt trace facility to JavaScript via the H5vccTraceEvent API: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/h5vcc/h5vcc_trace_event.idl

So in your JavaScript code, you can surround your functions with:

window.h5vcc.traceEvent.traceBegin('MyApp', 'Function1');

and

window.h5vcc.traceEvent.traceEnd('MyApp', 'Function1');

and then those results should appear in the Cobalt trace output.

Comment: Note also that we will be focusing on bringing better web inspector debugger support to Cobalt early 2018.